# Java method validation of a recursive method

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

In a Spring Boot application I have a service class annotated with `@Service`
and `@Validated`.
In this class I have a public instance method in which the arguments are annotated with constraint-annotations. Thus before method invocation the method's arguments are validated to validate if they comply to these constraints.
This works if the method is invoked from another class. But if this method is recursive its arguments are not being validated since the method is invoked from a class in which the method resides. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, no validation because of the self invocation. Do you realy need to re-validate your params even if they were validated at the first call? If you update the params through the recursive logic, you should just insure that your udpates will never make them unvalid. Or you can look for self-injection but depending on the complexitity of your recursive call, it could be heavy..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not using any shared state in the Service class, you could get a bean of the same type and call your recursive method. This, however, feels a bit hacky and wouldn't be my first option.

What I do recommend is moving the validations to the method code. This will solve your current issue, while allowing your validations to be extensible, and also allowing you to test them separately. Depending on their complexity, you can have them in a separate class, for example.